# How can I open the Microsoft Entourage email database file in an opensource email program?

Tags: open-source, ms-office, openoffice.org, email-client, entourage

Q: Is there a way to open Entourage emails with an open-source email viewer, simply by opening the Entourage database file?

CONTEXT: I have old emails in a Microsoft Entourage database, which I'd like to read with an open-source email viewer. I no longer have Entourage on my new Mac.

My Entourage email database file resides at this filepath (930 MB):

```
/Users/me/Documents/Microsoft\ User\ Data/Office\ 2004\ Identities/Main\ Identity/Database
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While your mail is still saved in the entourage database format, I wouldn't know a way to open it in open source email-clients, as it is a mostly undocumented format.

You could however try and get a 30-day trial of Office for Mac 2008, which still includes Entourage, or Office for Mac 2011, which has Outlook and should be able to import the Entourage format.

(Source : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2413370)

After that you would have to export the mails in the .mbox format, which is recognized by several OSS-Mailclients.

Answer (score 0):

This problem usually occurs when an Entourage `.rge` database files gets corrupted and becomes inaccessible.

There are several reasons behind the corruption of Entourage databases and some of them are listed below (to help you to analyze the problem behind the Database Daemon corruption):

- System or Entourage application shut down ungracefully.
- Entourage hangs and freeze up sometimes.
- Entourage items fails to launch.
- Fails to manage your personal data.
- All the precious E-mails, contacts, and other data inaccessible.

You may want to check this article: [Tips To Rebuild Entourage Mailbox After Lost Emails On Macintosh](http://www.macentouragerepair.com/rebuild-entourage-mailbox.php)